# I cannot edit the .g4 file in IDEA after creating it

Tags: intellij-idea, antlr

I am using ANTLR in IDEA. After installing the ANTLR v4 grammer plugin, i created Hello.g4 file in package `antlr`:

[image]

But IDEA did not recognise this file, and I was not able to edit it:

[image]

Comment: sorry I dont know how to add pictures. The IDEA regards the Hello.g4 as a dir.

Answer (score 1):

The question mark in the icon indicates that IntelliJ does not "know" how to handle this file type. When you first create a new file type (like `.g4`), IntelliJ will ask you how to open it. You apparently indicated something other than ANTLR or as plain text.

To change this, do the following:

1. go to `Preferences`
2. select `Editor`
3. select `File Types`
4. int the `Recognized file types` list, select `ANTLR V4 Grammar`
5. with the `+` button, add the `*.g4` pattern

[image]